# How to remove the matched values in two lists separately in python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop

I am facing a issue with my for loop in respect to lists.
I have two lists like shown below. Now I want to remove the name if the name in both lists matches. My code

```
Input:
 col = ['cat','dog','bird','fish']
col_names= [cat,bird]
r=[]
for i in col:
    print(i)
    if i in col_names: col_names.remove(i)
    r.append(col_names)
print(r)
```

then I am getting an output like this

```
r = [['dog','fish']] [['dog','fish']]
```

What I want is:

```
r =['dog','bird','fish'] ['cat','dog','fish']
```

Comment: What is this `r =['dog','bird','fish'] ['cat','dog','fish']`?

Comment: `r = [[i for i in col if i != n] for n in col_names]` OR `r = [list({n}.symmetric_difference(col)) for n in col_names]` Note that last option doesn't preserve order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler way to achieve this is using *nested list comprehension* :

```
>>> col = ['cat','dog','bird','fish']
>>> col_names= ['cat', 'bird']

>>> [[c for c in col if c !=cn] for cn in col_names]
[['dog', 'bird', 'fish'], ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']]
```

---

The code you shared is not logically correct. If you want to do it with explicit `for` loop, you can write it like this:

```
new_list = []
for cn in col_names:
    temp_list = []
    for c in col:
        if c != cn:
            temp_list.append(c)
    new_list.append(temp_list)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is col is edited everytime you remove an element from it because it is a pointer. If you want to achieve your desired output, you should create a copy first, like the following

```
col = ['cat','dog','bird','fish']
col_names= ['cat','bird','elephant']
r=[]
for name in col_names:
    tmp = col.copy() # Creates a copy of col list
    try:
        tmp.remove(name)
        r.append(tmp)
    except ValueError: # If name is not in the list
        pass # Don't do anything
print(r)
```

Output

```
[['dog', 'bird', 'fish'], ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']]
```